# continous function and closed graph

Tags: general-topology

$f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is such that it's graph is closed where $X$ is compact . Can someone provide me some examples that it is not necessarily true that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You need to at least show some thoughts for the problem, so we may assist you.

Answer (score 2):

The following example works, if $X$ is metric and has an accumulation point. Let $x_0 \in X'$, that is an accumulation point of $X$. Define $f \colon X \to \mathbb R$ by 
$$ f(x) := \begin{cases} d(x,x_0)^{-1}&x\ne x_0 \\ 0 & x = x_0 \end{cases}
$$